# Parsing a Haskell source file without an explicit 'module M where' header with GHC 7

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc

The guys at the Budapest Functional Programming meetup group finally convinced me to port [Tandoori](http://gergo.erdi.hu/projects/tandoori/) to GHC 7. Things are turning out OK, but I'm having a problem parsing `.hs` source files with no `module M where` header.

Here's a standalone version of the code that calls GHC's internal parser to parse source files:

```
module Main where

import SrcLoc
import FastString
import Outputable (showSDoc)
import Parser (parseModule)
import Lexer (unP, mkPState, ParseResult(..))
import StringBuffer (hGetStringBuffer)
import DynFlags (defaultDynFlags)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

parseMod src_filename = do 
  buf <- hGetStringBuffer src_filename
  let loc = mkSrcLoc (mkFastString src_filename) 1 0
      dflags = defaultDynFlags
  case unP Parser.parseModule (mkPState dflags buf loc) of
    POk pst rdr_module -> return rdr_module
    PFailed srcspan message -> error $ showSDoc message

main = do 
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [src_filename] -> parseMod src_filename
    _ -> error "Usage: parse-test filename.hs"
```

here's an input file that works:

```
foo = 1
```

here's another one that works:

```
module M where

foo = 1 
bar = 2
```

and here's one that doesn't:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
```

For this one, the output of the program above is:

```
*** Exception: parse error on input `='
```

Note that I'm using GHC's parser instead of something like [`haskell-src`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src) because the real code also uses the renamer from GHC.

Comment: And... what's the error message, if any? AFAIK, GHC requires you to have a function `main` in a module without header.

Comment: I've added the error message to the question. 

The requirement for a `main` is not checked by the parser, but somewhere much more downstream in the compiler pipeline. Note that you can load the two-liner example into e.g. GHCi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We simply prepend a module header line to the source we want to get parsed by the parser of GHC. Would this help you?

Comment: Who are 'you' in this context? Is there code available to determine the need for a syntetic module header and then prepend it?

Comment: 'You' or better I am myself. ;-) I have an application which knows that there is no module header and that it has to add it itself. If you don't know, that one could use a Haskell lexer to split the given sources in tokens and search for the `module` keyword. Which may only appear once or not at all. Which gives you your answer.

Comment: So basically you lex it, then look at the output, then parse it again?

I'm actually looking for a more sensible solution:) Invoking `ghc` directly from the command line seems to do a good job at compiling these programs so surely there is some code path inside GHC 7 that I could use.

Comment: No, I don't lex it, I know there is no module header. I was just proposing it this -- admittedly ugly -- workaround if you don't know wether you have to add a module header or not.